# WPF: How to store data from a list of data templates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox with "First Name" and "Last Name" options, a TextBox and "Add" button in a data template. I have OK and Cancel buttons in the modal dialog. 
"Add" button will add another row of the above datatemplate. 
Any item of this list can be edited before OK is pressed. 
How to get all the information added when OK is pressed?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you please add some code to make this question more real?

Comment: Do you want FirstName, LastName, TextBox's value after OK is pressed, or you want all records added to the collection ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the datatemplate as a listview's itemtemplate, bind the datatemplate to a viewModel. Set the `ObservableCollection<viewModel>` as the ItemsSource of the listview.
Hope it helps :)

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" />
```